# What service of aws can be used for developing question answer bank in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to develop question bank like application, where all people working in company can search for their query in there and there will be different set of answers already feed to the system. so this service should go and read answer already available with it and reply back to person with question with answer found in document.
Question would be like,

1. what is mean by ABC?
2. what are steps to run particular process?

There's similar services present in azure which saves these answer in plain document and keywords are used as intents there. I'm looking for similar or better service in aws for this.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Kendra, It returns specific answers to questions, giving users an experience that's close to interacting with a human expert ...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/what-is-kendra.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes amazon kendra with amazon Lex is answer to this question.